# Can't get ng-content's select to filter correctly

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to use `ng-content` to selectively display certain components in certain areas, but I'm not getting the filtering to work correctly.

I have a layout component which contains certain components which are marked with directives where they need to render.

```
    <standard-layout class="blah">
        <sample-navigation *navBarItem></sample-navigation>
        <sample-navigation *navBarItem></sample-navigation>
        <sample-form-1 *contentItem></sample-form-1>
        <sample-form-2 *contentItem></sample-form-2>
        <sample-form-3 *contentItem></sample-form-3>
        <sample-navigation *actionBarItem></sample-navigation>
        <sample-navigation *actionBarItem></sample-navigation>
    </standard-layout>
```

This is my `contentItem` directives:

```
@Directive(selector: '[contentItem]')
class ContentItemDirective implements AfterContentInit {
    final ViewContainerRef vcRef;
    final TemplateRef template;
    final ComponentResolver componentResolver;

    ContentItemDirective(this.vcRef, this.template, this.componentResolver);

    ComponentRef componentRef;

    @override
    ngAfterContentInit() async {
        final componentFactory =
        await componentResolver.resolveComponent(ContentItem);
        componentRef = vcRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
        (componentRef.instance as ContentItem)
            ..template = template;
    }

}
```

This is what my `ContentItem` looks like

```
@Component(
    selector: "content-item",
    host: const {
        '[class.content-item]': true,
    },
    template: """
        <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></template>
    """,
    directives: const [NgTemplateOutlet]
)
class ContentItem {
    TemplateRef template;
}
```

Inside the `standard-layout`'s template, when I do `<ng-content select=""></ng-content>`, it displays all the components as expected.

When I try and filter the components, it doesn't seem to work:

CSS Filtering displays nothing:

```
<ng-content select=".content-item"></ng-content>
```

Filtering on the `content-item` tag itself display nothing either:

```
<ng-content select="[content-item]"></ng-content>
```

I've tried many permutations of the `select=...` and just can't seem to get it working. Any ideas?

I'm on the Angular Dart 3.0.0 package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working using `@ContentChildren`

Inside my `StandardLayout` component, I filtered the inputs using:

```
@ContentChildren(ContentItemDirective)
QueryList<ContentItemDirective> contentItems;

@ContentChildren(ActionBarItemDirective)
QueryList<ActionBarItemDirective> actionBarItems;

@ContentChildren(NavBarItemDirective)
QueryList<NavBarItemDirective> navBarItems;
```

Now inside the `standard-layout` template, can loop through the items and display the template using `ngTemplateOutlet`

```
        <nav class="nav1" #nav1>
            <div *ngFor="let item of navBarItems">
                <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="item.template"></template>    
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="content" #content>    
            <div *ngFor="let item of contentItems">
                <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="item.template"></template>    
            </div>
        </div>

        <nav class="nav2" #nav2>
            <div *ngFor="let item of actionBarItems">
                <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="item.template"></template>    
            </div>              
        </nav>
```